# How to detach/attach logical volume from the compute node?

Tags: openstack, lvm

I have configured multi-node OpenStack on 3 nodes (controller, compute 01 and compute 02).

However, on compute nodes, the VMs are creating in the root directory -- I mean where my server Operating System sits -- but I haven't created separate volumes during server boot time so everything is in one volume.

Now I have separate physical disks on my servers so I don't want to disturb my OS on server, so I want to attach the new volumes to nova-compute. I have created logical volume (LVM) on new disks, but how can I detach the old one and add the new one?

I have searched but I only found out how to attach a volume to VMs which are in OpenStack Cloud.

Comment: your question is not clear, could you please reformulate, maybe make a quick ascii layout of drives, partitions, and folders concerned in this issue. it's not clear what your setup is.

Comment: Hi tatsu, i have 3 nodes configured on 3 physical servers, each 3 servers had 1 TB disk 56 cpu 256 GB RAM & os ubuntu 16.04. during boot i didn't partition the disk volume, like in windows volume C ,D,E..etc and C for os, so in my server case there is only one volume and where os (Operating System sits) and every thing what i store in the server,

Comment: so now if i create a VM in the openstack which will sits in compute nodes, and that VMs are also creating in the same volume where the server operating system, but now i have added other physical disk to my server(compute) and make it as LVM manageable disk and created a logical volume , my question was how to make a compute node use this newly created volume and how to make it stop using the volume which has ubuntu os of server. i hope it makes u understand better the issue i posted

Comment: no. this english is too broken, I can't understand. perhaps run it through : https://spellcheckplus.com/ or find a collegue to correct it for you.